# Output Even Numbers In an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop

I want to write a program that receives a list of numbers, converts them into an array, and output the even numbers in the array with Modulus Operator and For Loop.

The code does not run as expected:

```js
function even_num(){
  var submission = prompt("Enter Numbers:", ""); // receive list of numbers 
  var subarray = submission.split('');  // convert to array

  for(var i =1; i < subarray.length; i++){

    if( subarray[i] % 2 != 0){
      document.getElementById("return").innerHTML += subarray[i] + ",";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="even_num()">Even Number in an Array</button>
<p id = "return"></p>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of incorrect condition.
`i % 2` would give `0` for even numbers

```js
function even_num() {
  let submission = prompt("Enter Numbers:", "");
  let subarray = submission.split('');
  const result = document.getElementById("return");
  result.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < subarray.length; i++) {
    if (subarray[i] % 2 == 0) {//Condition here was incorrect
      result.innerHTML += subarray[i] + ",";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<button onclick="even_num()">Even Number in an Array</button>
<p id="return"></p>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your logic is slightly off.

Try changing

```
if( subarray[i] % 2 != 0){
```

to

```
if( subarray[i] % 2 === 0){
```

Complete:

```
    function even_num(){
        var submission = prompt("Enter Numbers:", ""); // receive list of numbers
        var subarray = submission.split('');  // convert to array

        for(var i =1; i < subarray.length; i++){
            if( subarray[i] % 2 === 0){
                document.getElementById("return").innerHTML += subarray[i] + ",";
            }
        }
    }
```